# Office 365 SharePoint adding items to a list cased on the items in another list

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint

I have 3 lists - control, parent and child. Whenever an item is added to the control list, I need to copy all the items in the parent into the child (while changing a little) After the process has happened a few times, the child list count will be a multiple of the parent list count, but the parent will remain constant.

I want this to happen when the user clicks the Save button on a new item in the control list.

I have written code in the PreSaveAction and put it in a Script editor web part in the New Item page of the control list.

The code does not perform as needed. I have added alerts so that I can follow what is going on. The last alert I get is in line 42 and it tells me the count on the parent list. I do not get the next alert in line 45 or any other thereafter. Note that there is no action between these two alerts, only a few commented lines. The control is added but the copy does not take place.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveAction()
 {
    var clientContext; 
    var web;
    var lists
    var inputList;
    var outputList;
    alert("before caml query");
//  var query = "<View Scope = 'RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Active'/>" + 
//       "<Value Type='Integer'>1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
    var query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Active'/>" + 
        "<Value Type='Integer'>1</Value></Eq></Where>";
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
    web = clientContext.get_web();
    lists = web.get_lists();
    inputList = lists.getByTitle('ParentList');
    outputList = lists.getByTitle('ChildList');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    // return only Active items
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(query);
    alert("in view xml");
    this.inputListItems = inputList.getItems(camlQuery); //Parent
    clientContext.load(inputListItems);
    alert("after loading list items");
    // The copying will be done in the succeeded function
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)); 
    return true;
};

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) 
{
    alert("start Query Succeeded");
    var inputItem = '';
    var outputItem = '';
    var parentID = 0;
    var parentTitle = '';
    var contolName = "blah";
    alert("Input List count = " + inputListItems.get_count());
    // get the reference to the control
    // var contolName = document.getElementsByName("Title")[0].value;
    alert("in control " + controlName);
    var listItemEnumerator = inputListItems.getEnumerator();
    alert("after setting Enumerator");
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) 
    {
        var inputItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        parentID = inputItem.get_id();
        parentTitle = inputItem.get_item('Title');
        // now create the copy in output
        // CreateOutputListItem(parentID, parentTitle, contolName);
        outputItem.set_item('Parent', parentTitle);
        outputItem.set_item('ParentID', parentID);
        outputItem.set_item('Control', contolName);
        outputItem.update();
        clientContext.load(outputItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onWriteSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onWriteFailed));
    }
}

function onWriteSucceeded(sender, args) {

    alert('Item created: ' + outputItem.get_id());
}

function onWriteFailed(sender, args) 
{

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}


function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know recall the "alert" mechanism's properties -- is it possible that you need to flush the output buffer?  Is it possible that the program _did_ advance, but stuck in a loop farther down, and never produced enough output to display the (buffered) output of line 45?

Comment: `The code does not perform as needed.` Error? ULS logs? Anything that can be of help without asking us to figure out what your environment is and replicating it to reproduce the issue?

Comment: As @Prune stated, skip the `alert` and use `console.log` instead, since it's non blocking.